# ExifTool | Return a list of moved files

Tags: bash, synology, exiftool

I'm using ExifTool on my Synology NAS to automatically sort all my pictures in folders with the following pattern: Year\Month\Day\Filename.extension

After sorted my files automatically, I need to start the process synoindex to index the new files in Synology Photostation. This process requires at least a directory or filename with should get indexed. 
Therefore I'm searching a method which returns all new file paths of the moved files (with ExifTool). Does anybody have a idea how to return these paths with ExifTool?

```
exiftool -d '%Y\%m\%d\%H.%M.%S%%-c.%%e' "-filename<CreateDate" '../Test'
```

Comment: If no solution exist using ExifTool, you could always create a token file before running your ExifTool process that you would afterward use with `find` to list all the files that are were created/modified more recently than the token file

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`-v` (verbose) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#v-NUM--verbose) and piped the output through sed(?) (sorry, not completely familiar with unix commands) to get a list of the changed files.

For every file that gets moved/renamed, there will be a line that indicates the move.  For example:
`'/old/path/to/file/OldName.jpg' --> '/new/path/to/file/NewName.jpg'`

That should be fairly easy to parse out the new filename.  There will be some additional lines that say `Setting new values from…`, possibly `Created directory`, that can be ignored.

Files that are not moved/renamed will have these lines
`Setting new values from FILE`
`Nothing changed in FILE`